# Export After Effects animation to SVG + CSS?

Tags: svg, export, software-recommendation, css, adobe-after-effects

Is it possible to export After Effects animations to SVG + CSS? I'm okay with a commercial solution for this.

I know about Bodymovin' and Lottie, but I would like to avoid going down this path, because I believe that native animations with CSS perform much better than what Lottie is able to deliver, since it relies on JavaScript.

Comment: Depends on what features of after effects you are willing to sacrafice. But generally there is no good one.

Comment: Thanks joojaa. I'll gladly accept your comment as an answer, if you write it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding a bit on @joojaa's comment, posting what I know now:

After Effects (AE) can do a lot more than what is possible with SVG+CSS, so it's not technically possible to just export an AE animation to SVG+CSS. If SVG+CSS is the desired end product, use another animation software tool than AE. (I'm not a designer, so don't know what to recommend.)

Exporting to a Bodymovin' JSON and running the animation with Lottie for Web makes it possible to do a lot more, but there are still some limitation, see https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web#ae-feature-support. The result will be best if the designer knows about what works and what does not. I had issues with letter spacing being completely off and elements not being hidden when trying to use one of the optimized versions of lottie.js.